# Linq-to-EF with nullable decimals & math functions

Tags: .net, sql-server, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a Clinics table in SQL2008 which has nullable decimal Latitude and Longitude columns (nullable as I don't have coords for all clinics).

I'm using Linq-to-EF and would like to calculate / sort the records by the distance from a given point.

For simplicity's sake, let's say the distance calculation can be:

```
√¯( (ClinicLat - PointLat) ^ 2 + (ClinicLng - PointLng) ^ 2 )
```

(The first symbol is meant to be square root)

The closest I came is:

```
Math.Sqrt(
        Math.Pow((double)((c.Latitude ?? 0) - latNotNull), 2.0)
        + Math.Pow((double)((c.Longitude ?? 0) - lngNotNull), 2.0)
    )
```

But that gives the error:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Double Sqrt(Double)' method
```

I thought about using a UDF but EF Code First doesn't allow it. I don't want to use a stored proc as I'd like to write the query & manage it in the C#. Do I have any options?

Comment: I'm confused. Is it linq to SQL or EF?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek It's EF, he said he's using Code First.

Comment: Updated the question to Linq-to-Entities. Sorry, a bit new to this Linq stuff. What difference would it make, out of interest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`SqlFunctions.SquareRoot`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.squareroot%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`SqlFunctions.Square`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.square%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods:

```
SqlFunctions.SquareRoot(
        SqlFunction.Square(c.Latitude - latNotNull)
        + SqlFunctions.Square(c.Longitude - lngNotNull)
    )
```

They will be transformed into proper TSQL functions calls.

You shouldn't even have to do the `null` check at all.

Comment: Looks like just what I need. Thanks a mill.

Comment: Would Linq-to-SQL be any different?

Comment: Yes, as stated on MSDN: *This function can only appear within a LINQ to Entities query*.

Comment: How would you do it for Linq-to-SQL, if you don't mind?

Comment: @Sean For LinqToSql http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882648(v=vs.110).aspx  Since Math.Sqrt is not in the unsupported list, it is supported.  Use Math.Sqrt

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but `Math.Sqrt` should work just fine in LINQ to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

> sort the records by the distance

The order of the records will be the same without the Square Root.

Comment: erm... shoulda' been a comment?

Comment: No, it's an option.  So it's an answer.

Comment: The question is asking how do do maths in a Linq-to-EF query, I don't see how this answers the question. Its a very good comment though ;)

Comment: Thanks, I had done that already, but was interested in the Maths, as eventually I'll have to use the 'real' formula, which is a bit more complex...